# Gridbaglayout in ScrollPane in Splitpane

Tags: java, swing, scrollpane

I have a ScrollPane in a SplitPane and the ScrollPane contains a Gridbag layout panel.
 I like to add horizontal filling Buttons to it. 
Setting weightx and filling does not help at all. 
I already tried it by using the dividers property listener, but nothing works.

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Sorry for no code, I will post it later, because I am at my mobile now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be no problem:

```java
// ScrollPane in a SplitPane
var scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
var splitPane = new JSplitPane();
splitPane.setLeftComponent(scrollPane);
splitPane.setRightComponent(new JLabel("dummy"));

// ScrollPane contains a Gridbag layout panel
var gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
var panel = new JPanel(gridBagLayout);
scrollPane.setViewportView(panel);

// add horizontal filling Buttons
var gbc = new GridBagConstraints(
    0, RELATIVE, 1, 1, 1.0, 0.0, 
    CENTER, HORIZONTAL, new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2), 0, 0);
panel.add(new JButton("first"), gbc);
panel.add(new JButton("second"), gbc);

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, splitPane);
```